# How to use WebView for iOS app using Xamarin?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios

I want to open a URL in iOS app using Xamarin.

When app opens my website URL run and open in iOS app. So basically it works as a browser.

I am new to iOS development, so I have no idea how to build this type of app. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a UiWebView in your view.
For launch url, use `LoadRequest()` or for implement HTML code use `LoadHtmlString()`.

More details can be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/webview/).